# How to remove data within a multi-line cell that comes after a few line breaks

Tags: excel, excel-formula, replace

I have an excel spreadsheet which has content I don't need, following content I do need, within each cell, with a few line breaks in between. I would like to remove the bad content, using some sort of formula which states that in each cell, the line breaks & anything that follows them should be removed, for example:

cell A1 -
Three blind mice, three blind mice

See how they run, see how they run

They all ran after the farmer's wife

She cut off their tails with a carving knife

Did you ever see such a sight in your life as three blind mice?

Star Light, Star Bright
Twinkle, Twinkle, Little Star
Jack and Jill
I’m a Little Teapot

There are multiple line breaks between the nursery rhyme & the list of nursery rhyme titles that follow, but they aren't showing that way above. The image linked below shows it better.

In the above example, how can I remove the line breaks and the list of nursery rhymes, all I want to keep are the lyrics at the top?

Here is a screenshot of an example cell
[example cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqTrc.jpg)

Thanks

I've tried using the replace tool, but I can't figure out how to accomplish this.

Comment: May want to reference: https://superuser.com/questions/370066/how-to-search-for-newline-or-linebreak-characters-in-excel  I'm not sure if you're asking to do this programatically via formula or though find/replace. link shows find/replace, answer below uses formula

Answer (score 0):

- find() return the starting position of a string with a string
- char(10) is the "line feed" in asci (10) getting converted to character which can be searched
- LEFT() simply returns the left part of the string up to the enter.

so..

`=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),A1)-1)`

we find the first occurrence of 3 line breaks in a row.

We put the formula in Cell B2 then copy and past values over your original data if you truly no longer need it.  Or just reference B2... and keep original values.

Reference: https://superuser.com/questions/370066/how-to-search-for-newline-or-linebreak-characters-in-excel

So:

[image]

Gives us:

[image]

We simply look for 3 consecutive line breaks and Keep everything to the left of it.

Comment: You gotta do `-1` anyway, or it'll keep `CHAR(10)`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I realised that my example didn't fully represent my problem. I have single line breaks in the content I want to keep, but then multiple line breaks before the content I don't want. Your solution helped me remove everything after the first single line break, but I only want to remove the data after the multiple line breaks.

Comment: Modify the find to look for two consecutive line breaks. and then use that as your "end" for the left.  not enough time to look at it now   but your find would be something like `=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),A1))`

Comment: That formula didn't work, if you manage to give me the correct one when you have more time, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @sam I don't understand the requirements then.  the formula I used worked with the example I created.   I updated my answer to show it. So I don't fully understand the situation then.

Comment: @sam  it's just a matter of adding another char(10) then  We're looking for 3 or more in a row; after that truncate.